# elsarticle frontmatter: Overfull \hbox has occurred while \output is active

Tags: templates, warnings, elsarticle, front-matter

Minimal working example

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

leads to

> ```
> Overfull \hbox (2.22221pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active []
> ```

The same warning occurs if I use the original template from:

- https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions
- direct link: https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip

I'm using

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)

and my packages are all up to date (as of 30.Oct.2019) and I have the newest version of `elsarticle`: https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle (06.April.2019)

Comment: Try updating the `elsarticle` package in the MiKTeX package manager. In the current version this has been fixed. It was a case of a missing `%`. There's this comment in the code now: `}% <--- I added this on May 19th, 2019`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your answer, but MikTeX tells me "There are currently no updates available. Try again tomorrow." I checked the `elsartilce` package on my computer which was installed on the 04.06.19(June) with the version of 06.04.19(April), which is the current package at https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle

Comment: Odd. This version has been around for a while now, so it should be available. Perhaps try a different mirror. And don't trust the dates. My TeXLive 2019 version of `elsarticle` is dated `2019/02/25`, the documentation is dated `2019/04/06`, and it has the comment-from-the-future from `2019/05/19` :-) Search for your version and look for the line that says `Preprint submitted to \ifx\@journal\@empty`. Some 6 lines below this one there should be a single `}` in a line of its own. Edit the file and make sure it reads `}%` instead.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. :-D
Ps the file was located at `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\elsarticle\elsarticle.cls`

Comment: Great! Warnings are annoying. Although this specific one wouldn't do any visible harm. However it is strange that you don't have the `elsarticle` update available...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sorry, but CTAN, is THE server for TeX-packages. It is the one MiKTeX gets the packages from. If CTAN does not have this update, this means this update does not officially exists. If you fixed the bug, please take care that this update get public available, but don't spread the claim that it is officially out. As long as it not on https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle it is a local branch on your PC, but not an update.

Comment: I know what CTAN is ;-) But I went to check on CTAN and the bug is still there, so apparently I _did_ fix this in my version of `elsarticle` (which is odd, because I usually don't change files in my TeX distribution). I'll get your question reopened and post an answer. (Off-topic: last week I was writing a paper and thought to myself: "cool, they fixed that pesky bug in `elsarticle`"... Apparently not. I'll report the bug again.)

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in `elsarticle` introduced some time in 2018 (in TeXLive 2017 it's fine), caused by the usual missing `%` at the end of the line. The guilty definition is:

```
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
     \let\@oddhead\@empty
     \let\@evenhead\@empty
     \def\@oddfoot
       {\hbox to \textwidth%
        {\ifnopreprintline\relax\else
        \@myfooterfont%
         \ifx\@elsarticlemyfooteralign\@elsarticlemyfooteraligncenter%
           \hfil\@elsarticlemyfooter\hfil%
         \else%
         \ifx\@elsarticlemyfooteralign\@elsarticlemyfooteralignleft%
           \@elsarticlemyfooter\hfill{}%
         \else%
         \ifx\@elsarticlemyfooteralign\@elsarticlemyfooteralignright%
           {}\hfill\@elsarticlemyfooter%
         \else%
               Preprint submitted to \ifx\@journal\@empty%
                 Elsevier%
            \else\@journal\fi\hfill\@date\fi%
         \fi%
         \fi%
         \fi%
         }                     % <------------
       }%
     \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

where the line marked with `% <--` should contain a `%` right after the `}`. (Funnily enough, most of the end of line `%` in this definition are useless :-)

Here are four options to fix this (all except 2 should go *after* `elsarticle` is loaded, or they will have no effect):

1. Copy the definition above to your document and add a `%` right after the `}` (and make sure to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the definition):

   ```latex
            \fi%
            \fi%
            }% <--- Here
          }%
        \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
   ```
2. Make a local copy of `elsarticle.cls` and do the same.
3. Patching with `\patchcmd` is tricky<sup>1</sup> because the extra space is between two `}`. But it's possible with some brace hacking and `\romannumeral`. Adding this to your preamble should also fix the problem:

   ```latex
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\ps@pprintTitle
     {\fi\fi\fi\fi}
     {\fi\fi\fi\fi
      \afterassignment\fix@elsarticle\let\@tempa}
     {}{\FailedToPatch}
   \def\fix@elsarticle{\iffalse{\fi}\romannumeral-`0}
   \makeatother
   ```
4. LaTeX3's regex engine doesn't abide by the same rules as `\patchcmd`, so you can directly replace `} }` by `}}`:

   ```latex
   \usepackage{regexpatch}
   \makeatletter
   \regexpatchcmd\ps@pprintTitle
     {\cE\}\ \cE\}}{\cE\}\cE\}}
     {}{\FailedToPatch}
   \makeatother
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Patching that bug with `etoolbox` is tricky because the patch would need to replace the sequence `} }` by `}}`. The issue with this is that you can't have unbalanced braces in the argument of `\patchcmd` (of any macro, in fact). Actually, the braces are not really necessary, but we need some way to distinguish the space we *actually* want to remove from, say, the one between `Preprint` and `submitted`.

The end of the definition of `\ps@pprintTitle` reads:

```latex
%            V space we want to remove
\fi\fi\fi\fi} }\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
```

The patch I proposed above hooks at the four consecutive `\fi` in the macro and appends `\afterassignment\fix@elsarticle\let\@tempa` to them:

```latex
%                              space we want to remove V
\fi\fi\fi\fi\afterassignment\fix@elsarticle\let\@tempa} }
```

When the code execution arrives there, the four `\fi` do their thing as usual and disappear. `\afterassignment` stores the token `\fix@elsarticle` in a temporary memory which will be retrieved after the next assignment. The very next thing is `\let\@tempa}`. This instruction stores the token `}` in `\@tempa` (the same as `\egroup`) and as a consequence, removes it from the token stream. However now (keep this in mind) we have unbalanced TeX's brace count by removing a `}`.

But notice that what just happened (`\let`) was an assignment. TeX now triggers the `\afterassignment` token `\fix@elsarticle`, which then expands to its definition. So far, the input stream looks like this:

```latex
%                            V space we want to remove
\iffalse{\fi}\romannumeral-`0 }
```

Now the `\iffalse` expands consuming the `{`. This brace removal balances out the other brace we removed before, and the very next token is a `}`, which acts as that same brace we removed. Now all that's left is `` \romannumeral-`0 } ``. `\romannumeral` starts by reading in `` -`0 ``, which is some negative value. Then, as other TeX primitives which scan a number, it consumes an optional space after the number, which *finally* removes the pesky space. However, since the read integer is negative, the expansion of `\romannumeral` is empty and the rest of the code runs fine. What a ride :-)

Comment: The third option seems good, because it does not need to copy the entire definition. But how does it work? Mainly, why `\romannumeral`?

Comment: @LaTeXer I added an explanation about the `\romannumeral` trickery and a fourth option.

Comment: Not sure if this is because Overleaf seems to have recently updated its error log functionality, but I'm finding that (1) doesn't work, while (3) and (4) make the error go away, although Overleaf still says "Your code has errors that need to be fixed before the auto-compile can run" (even though no errors appear under this message).

Comment: @WillG Hm... I just tried the four solutions here with the example in the question and they work (note that (1) needs `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to work; I'll add that to the answer).  Can you show an example code that doesn't work?  Also, which version of TeX Live are you using on Overleaf? (you can find that under the Menu tab)

Comment: Actually, (4) seems to be fully working for me now, for some reason. Not sure if refreshing the page could have made a difference? Was using pdfLaTeX compiler for TeX live version 2020, but probably no longer relevant since it's working now :)

Comment: @WillG (4) is a fancy version of (3), so either should work...  Maybe Overleaf had some stray cache file that got in the way, or some auxiliary file was damaged.  Good to know it's working! :D