# Definitive way to pre- and append code, or patch commands?

Tags: macros, etoolbox, patching

Consider the following example: we have a command `\mycmd`, defined in some pacakge as:

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mycmd}{%
    <original source code>
}
```

we want to patch this command, in the sense of pre- and appending code. These may contain anything, including `\if` `\else` constructs wrapping the original code. The *direct* way to do this would be of course to originally defining the command this way. If the command already exists we could patch it by deleting it first using `etoolbox`'s `\undef`:

```latex
\undef{\mycmd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mycmd}{%
    <pre code>
    <original source code>
    <post code>
}
```

**My question:**

It seems that `etoolbox`'s facilities (`\appto`, `\apptocmd`, etc.) do not work in all circumstances.

> Is there any way to achieve this patching without having to literally copy paste the original source code (but with 100% the same behaviour in all circumstances)?

This is sort of a follow up question to [Safe way of redefining \- only for math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529402)

Comment: It depends a bit on _what_ you want to patch. Most of the time you can use `\pretocmd` to prepend and `\apptocmd` to append to a macro, and `\patchcmd` to patch some part of it. Though some times patching is tricker ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515199/134574)), and some times it's not at all possible. So again, it depends...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This example is out of the scope of this question. I am restricting it clearly to pre- and appending code. Although that code should, as mentioned, be allowed to contain anything including wrapping the original source code with `\if` `\else`. I updated the title to make it more clear.

Comment: That's why it was an example ;-) Looking at your linked question, this should do the job, with `xpatch` loaded: `\xpretocmd\-{\ifmmode \mycmd \else}{}{\ERROR}\xapptocmd\-{\fi}{}{\ERROR}`. Patching with unbalanced `\if...\fi` is usually not a problem. What can be a complication is ubalanced `{...}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik oh nice, I wasn't aware of this package. Although it says in the documentation that it isn't compatible with `xparse` defined commands, which is a bummer.

Comment: `xpatch` uses the patching mechanism from `etoolbox`, but adds extra checking in case the command is robust (`\DeclareRobustCommand`) or contains optional arguments. And `xparse`-defined commands _can_ be patched, yes (they are macros like any other), but they should not, that's why the author of `xpatch` didn't implement that.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You wanna make this an answer so the question isn't marked as "unanswered" anymore?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Why shouldn't `xparse` commands be patched? After all, they are macros like any other?

Comment: @Andrew It's more of a philosophical issue (of course you can patch, if you know how). A _big_ issue with maintaining LaTeX2e is that if you change the tiniest bit of code you will break something that relied on its internals. `expl3` tries to improve on that with a harder separation of internal code, so that it can be changed as long as functionality remains (try [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250350/134574) for example). The same goes for `xparse` code: as long as functionality remains, implementation can be freely changed, and whatever patch you have may stop working at any time.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Great. Thanks! Maintainability makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: there is no “definitive way”.

How (and if it is possible) to patch (or prepend or append to) a command depends on how it's defined (`\def`, `\newcommand`, `\DeclareRobustCommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand`), if it takes arguments, what are the contents of the command, and *what* you want to patch in that command.

---

**Macro without arguments:** The simplest case is if the command doesn’t take arguments. In this case the macro is (in `expl3` parlance) a “token list”, and you can just expand the macro and do whatever with its contents. Everything inside that token list is (unsurprisingly) a token, so you can traverse it, query its contents, add and remove tokens at your will. Prepending and appending in this case is trivial (see the definition of `\g@addto@macro` in `latex.ltx`), and the difficulty of patching something in the middle again depends on what you want to replace.

**Macro with arguments:** A trickier case is when the macro has arguments. In this case you cannot simply expand it because when you expand it tries to grab arguments, and you don’t have these here (and if you do, you lose the macro parameters inside the definition, which you probably don’t want).

In this case you have to use a proper patching command (like `etoolbox`’s `\patchcmd`). The process of patching consists in turning the entire definition into a string (using `\meaning`), separating the `<parameter text>` from the `<replacement text>`, doing the replacement, and then rescanning the string and redoing the definition using `\scantokens`, hoping nothing goes wrong in this process (see an explanation of that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498229/134574)).

The problem with patching is the `\scantokens` part, which assumes one single catcode regime, and depending how the macro was defined, that is not the case. Take for example LaTeX 2ε’s `\rem@pt` macro. If you do `\meaning\rem@pt` you get `\rem@pt=macro:#1.#2pt->#1\ifnum #2>\z@ .#2\fi` (suppose you just want to replace the `.` for a `,`: seems easy enough). The problem with patching this one is that in `#1.#2pt`, the `p` and `t` are catcode-12 tokens, whereas the `p` and `t` in `\rem@pt` must be catcode-11 so that you can actually do the definition. `\patchcmd` will refuse to do anything here unless (it's not impossible, but you have to be careful). There are cases where this is outright impossible with `\patchcmd` (try patching anything into the definition of `\end` in a LaTeX older than 01-10-2019).

**How it is defined (and optional arguments):** Supposing that the macro has a well-behaved catcode regime, and that you can patch it using `\patchcmd`. When you define `\newcommand\foo[1][]{a#1b}` the *actual* definition of `\foo` is not in `\foo`, but in `\\foo` (two backslashes in the name), so you have to patch the latter instead. This case is quite easy: load `xpatch` and use `\xpatchcmd` (or `\xpretocmd` or `\xapptocmd`) instead. `xpatch` will do the thinking for you and will figure out that it needs to patch `\\foo` instead (and will use `etoolbox`’s `\patchcmd` for that). If the command was defined with `xparse` then `xpatch` won’t help either (these commands *can* be patched, but they are not meant to, so `xpatch` doesn’t even try to support that).

**What you want to patch:** You mentioned unbalanced `\if`...`\fi` in your question, but that’s actually not a problem. Unbalanced conditionals are problematic inside other conditionals, which is not the case when patching. The problem here is unbalanced `{`...`}`, since the patching macros assume balanced braces. Depending on what you want to do you can work-around (look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515199/134574) for an example), but it's really in a case-by-case basis.

**`l3regex` to the rescue:** What gets closest to a “definitive” way to patch is using `l3regex` (and `regexpatch`). The `regexpatch` package uses the LaTeX3 regular expression engine (`l3regex`) to match and replace tokens set under different catcode settings so that you can patch the trickier stuff. Using `\regexpatchcmd\command{<search-regex>}{<replace-regex>}{<true code>}{<false code>}` will look for the `<search-regex>` in the definition of the `\command` and will replace by the `<replace-regex>`. The package, same as `xpatch`, takes care of robust commands and commands with optional arguments. Take a look at the [`l3regex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#part.27) and [`regexpatch`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/regexpatch/regexpatch.pdf) documentation for the syntax of the regular expressions and the patching commands.